# Is there an Iterable which allows Iterable.remove() to be called by another instance?

Tags: java, collections, guava

Is there a Guava Iterator (or methodology) for List objects which allows two iterator instances to exist - in the same memory scope - while allowing the remove() operation? (Bonus point: if it works for a Collection).

Example use case: an outer and an inner iteration through a collection, where the inner loop might decide to remove an element and the outer loop would subsequently skip it.

Imagine how it would benefit the following concept code (which uses Guava static imports) by reducing the number of elements to compare in the loop and also removing the need to remove empty sets from the list at the end:

```
private <T> Set<Set<T>> disjointify(Collection<Set<T>> sets) {
    List<Set<T>> disjoint = newArrayList(sets);
    for (Set<T> set1 : disjoint) {
        for (Set<T> set2 : filter(disjoint, not(equalTo(set1)))) {
            if (!intersection(set1, set2).isEmpty()) {
                // this wouldn't be safe for a Set<Set<T>>
                set1.addAll(set2);
                set2.clear();
            }
        }
    }
    return newHashSet(filter(disjoint, NO_EMPTIES));
}
private static final Predicate<Set<?>> NO_EMPTIES = new Predicate<Set<?>>() {

    @Override
    public boolean apply(Set<?> input) {
        if (input == null || input.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Note: one can easily imagine creating the implementation - especially for LinkedList - I'm just asking if one already exists here.

For the record, if an efficient Iterable did already exist, and worked for Sets, then the use case would look like the following (I have created my own very inefficient Iterable which achieves this, but it is 50 lines long and ludicrously inefficient - so I use the original code above):

```
private <T> void disjointify(Set<Set<T>> sets) {
    for (Set<T> set1 : nestable(sets)) {
        Iterator<Set<T>> it = filter(nestable(sets), not(equalTo(set1))).iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Set<T> set2 = it.next();
            if (!intersection(set1, set2).isEmpty()) {
                set1.addAll(set2);
                it.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that such an implementation does not exist in standard libraries.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just filter the outer look with NO_EMPTIES? Since filter is evaluated during iteration, any newly empty sets would not be returned in the filtered list / outer loop.

Otherwise, I don't think so. You would get a `ConcurrentModificationException` on the outter loop.

Comment: That would result in a broken algorithm, I'll leave the test case for the reader ;-)

Comment: How so? Since empty sets are filtered out at the end.

Comment: the inner loop creates the empty sets, which may never be reached by the outer loop again. This is getting a little off topic ;-) the question is about Iterables, not other ways to write the example use case.